# Print 5th Word from the Title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get the 5th word from a title to use it as a breadcrumb path. Also it need to print until meet special character like , or ( like here:

Ex: Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

Result: Amet

```
current(explode(',', get_the_title( $post->ID )));
```

Comment: When you say, "print until meet special character", do you mean any character that is not alphanumeric?

Comment: please provide some specific examples of inputs and expected results

Comment: Yes, but in this case It only need - , ( [

Comment: When I use current(explode(' ', I get the first word only. What have to be to get the fifth?

Comment: @tw8sw8dw8, can you please give feedback and/or accept if any of the answers below worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first explode your string separated by space  ' '. From the array you get after this,  the 4th index will contain your 5th word. Using str_replace you can replace the comma in your 5th word and you will get the output Amet

```
$myvalue = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
$arr = explode(' ',trim($myvalue));
echo $arr[4]; // get 5th word 
$str = str_replace( ',', '', $arr[4] ); 
// Display the  string separated from comma
echo($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that will get you any word position with a list of chars you want to stop at.

```
$str = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit Amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';

echo getNthWord($str, ' ', 5, [',','(','[']);

function getNthWord($input, $delimiter, $numWord, $replaceChars = []) {
  $split = explode($delimiter, $input);
  $word = $split[ $numWord - 1 ];

  return str_replace($replaceChars, '', $word);
}
```